# Node.js Server Side applications written in Typescript vs JS (ES5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular, typescript

Note: By regular js I refer to the **ES5** version of js.

I am currently setting up the foundation to a project. The tech stack that I currently have choosen to go with is **Node.js** for the back-end w/ **Angular2** for the front-end/client-side and I am using Gulp as my build tool. In addition I have chosen to use **Typescript** for Angular.

I have already set up the gulpfile to do everything necessary for an optimal Typescript build. In fact the way I set everything up gulp can handle all the Typescript in the application, which led me to the realization it might be useful to write the whole application in Typescript vs regular (Node.js - Server) js. Although, when looking for pros and cons of doing so I have been unable to find any real references and instances where people recommend doing so or if it is better to just write the server side of the application without utilizing TS.

**In short my question**: Is it optimal to write the back and front end utilizing the Javascript superset Typescript? Are there any real Pros or Cons? I would appreciate any 'real' experiences. For example if there where any hurdles/workarounds that occurred or what made TS in server and client optimal in your case?

Thank you in advance, have a great day!

Comment: If it makes *you* productive - it's "optimal". Otherwise it's not.

Comment: In my apps I tend to strive to share as much code as possible (think validation) between browser and server because of DRY and single-point-of-truth -- I don't want to have to fix bugs twice. As such I tend to want both to be as similar as possible to aid code reuse. The platform specific stuff gets factored out as "drivers". So for me I'd want to use either Typescript on both or plain ES5 on both

Comment: @zerkms, although your statement is valid it doesn't help with the question.To rephrase does having typescript in both cases have any performance enhancements, provide stability, allow you to integrate other libraries with ease, etc... I am looking for to contrast options utilizing experiences where developers did the before mentioned. As mentioned in the question there are really no threads, posts or any other streams of information where the specific instance of changing the server scripting language shows any improvements to the applications functionality. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you asked is subjective and varies from a case to case dramatically. For that reason it's only your experience that matters.

Comment: @slebetman, thank you for your response, this was helpful in organizing my thoughts. Considering in the past with Angular 1 and Node.js used ES5 having the option to use either has really stumped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it optimal to write the back and front end utilizing the Javascript superset Typescript?

I would say yes : https://medium.com/@basarat/typescript-won-a4e0dfde4b08

But of course it is my opinion. The key choice is if you want *statically analyzable code*. It does help with tooling at the very least. More on *why typescript* https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html.